# Ionic2 Change view dynamically

Tags: dynamic, view, ionic-framework, angular, ionic2

I have toggle button on the page, once its clicked, then the current page view would change to different html.

I have tired changing `@Page`, but once its loaded, I can't seem to change it again.

```
@Page({
    templateUrl: isTrue ? 'build/pages/detail/page-by-page-view.html' : 'build/pages/detail/chapter-by-chapter-view.html'
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Page()` is an annotation. Angular2 processes this upon loading of the component (which `@Page()` technically is). It is not part of Zone change detection, so changing a variable won't do a thing. Not even after calling `applicationRef.tick()`.

A solution could be to use an `*ngIf` directive and merge your template files

Comment: do you have example usage for `*ngIf` with template including?

Comment: Merge your templates into one file, with in the first top element from `page-by-page-view.html`: `*ngIf="isTrue"` and in the other one `*ngIf="!isTrue"`

Comment: @Basit Or find a solution to reload the page when clicking on the button. That might work :)

Comment: :) ya, I was avoiding that, because button is on setting page. but I think  i will go with `*ngIf`. best would have been changing template dynamically.. rather then ngif. I will still wait for someone else to come up some other answer, if not, then I will accept this as answer.